# UserHierachy module for sugarCRM 6.5.2

Tags: sugarcrm

I have upgraded my SugarCRM 5.1 to 6.5.2. Now i want add Zukars_Hierarchy module  but does not support for 6.5.2. How should i do this ? How to develop custom module for user Hierarchy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for User Hierarchy Module For SugarCRM 6.5.*  please visite this site  and fallow the steps http://amolbansode.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/user-hierarchy-module-for-sugar-crm-6-5/